# Cargdor y Listador de un struct con dos variables y un array

Tags: array, c, struct, vectores

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio donde el enunciado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto cree un struct primero para el vector y otro struct donde incluyo las variables y el vector

```
struct CUPOS_STRUCT{
    char codigo_especie[4];
    float toneladas;
};

struct capturas{
    char cod_empresa[5];
    char cod_barco[4];
    struct CUPOS_STRUCT cupos_struct[2];
};
```

Y despues de eso armo la funcion cargadora y listadora

```
void carga_capturas(){
    struct capturas b;
    struct CUPOS_STRUCT cupos_struct;
    int n,n1,i;
    FILE *archcapturas;
    archcapturas= fopen("archcapturas","wb");
    printf("Cantidad de entradas? \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Ingrese: Cod Empresa   Cod Barco\n");
        scanf("%s %s", b.cod_empresa, b.cod_barco);
        printf("Cuantas especies quiere ingresar\n");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        for (i=0; i<n1; i++){
            printf("Ingresar: Codigo de especie  y toneladas\n");
            scanf ("%s %f",b.cupos_struct[i].codigo_especie, &b.cupos_struct[i].toneladas);
        }
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(struct capturas), 1,archcapturas);
    }
    fclose(archcapturas);
    archcapturas= fopen("archcapturas","rb");
    fread(&b,sizeof(struct capturas), 1,archcapturas);
    while(!feof(archcapturas)) {
        printf ("\n\nCod Empresa   Cod Barco\n");
        printf("%s %s\n", &b.cod_empresa, &b.cod_barco);
        printf("Codigo de especie  y toneladas\n");
        for (i=0; i<2; i++){
            printf("%s  %.0f\n",&b.cupos_struct[i].codigo_especie, b.cupos_struct[i].toneladas);
        }
        fread(&b,sizeof(struct capturas), 1,archcapturas);
    }
    fclose(archcapturas);
}
```

El problema que tengo es cuando aca printf("Cuantas especies quiere ingresar\n");  Ingreso 2 por ejemplo y despues en el siguiente barco 1

El listador me muestra los dos barcos pero con 1 especie cada una porque queda guardado el 1 y el 2 no, es decir la posicion.
Intente usando ese for que puse con <2 porque yo se que si o si es 0 o 1. Pero nose bien como controlar si es posicion 0 y 1 o solo 0.

Si alguien me puede ayudar
Muchas gracias !!!

Comment: A ver si tengo claro el problema. El problema es saber si son 1 o 2 registros los que tienes que mostrar en lo de codigo de  especie y tonelada? @FrancoBenettini

Comment: Exactamente. Porque cuando ingreso en el primer barco 2 especies y en el siguiente barco 1 especie. Me toma el numero 1 y me muestra solo 1 especie por barco

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 posibilidades. 1. Puedes guardar la cantidad de cupos dentro de `capturas`. 2. Puedes crear un `codigo_especie` que indique si la entrada es valida o no. El codigo de especie invalido puede ser `"\0"`, y entonces cuando vayas a mostrar usas `strlen` para ver la longitud del codigo. Si es `0`, entonces no muestras el registro.

Comment: Un par de notas sobre tu código. `CUPOS_STRUCT` es un mal nombre. Primero, los nombres que son todo mayúsculas deberían ser reservados para los macros. Y segundo, porque pones `_STRUCT` al final? Luego cuando uses el tipo `struct CUPOS_STRUCT` vas a ser redundante escribiendo `struct` dos veces. Igual el nombre del campo `cupos_struct`, porque añadir `_struct` al final si ya sabes lo que es?

Comment: Y sobre esto: `int n,n1,i;`. Sin ver el resto del codigo no es posible saber lo que es cada variable. Porque no cambiar los nombres a `cantidad_entradas`, `cantidad_especies`, y declararlos donde los uses? Eso hara que tu codigo sea mucho mas facil de leer y entender. De otro modo tendras que llevar una tabla mental, `n -> Cantidad de entradas`, `n1 -> Cantidad de especies`, etc. Añadir esa carga mental solo complica mas el escribir codigo.

Comment: Y con respecto a `fflush(stdin);`, eso no funciona en todos lados. Hay mejores alternativas que si son portables.

Comment: Genial, esas cosasa que me dijiste ya las arregle.
Respecto a fflush(stdin); que otras opciones puedo usar?

Y por el problema del listador, estoy viendo si me funciona lo que me dijiste por ahora, no llegue a mucho

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione la recomendacion. Sobre la
alternativa a `fflush(stdin)`, lo mas sencillo es seguir la
primera recomendacion [que se da
aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).
Puedes usar `getchar` para leer caracteres del stream hasta
que encuentres un salto de linea o un eof. (Una funcion que contenga esto, y
listo. `char c = '\0'; do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF); `)